# Why doesn't Chart.js display my output (result of a const function)?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

my issue is that Chart.js won't display the array that results from my function (the array I called "uno"). It seems like the chart receives no data, but I'm sure the function has an output. You can look at code and output here [codepen](https://codepen.io/dreamtheater96/pen/eYNyRdo), but I'll put it below as well:

HTML:

```
<div id="linechartContainer">

    <canvas id="Chartline">

        <canvas>

      </div>
```

JS:

```
var myJSON = [

  {
    "": 0,
    "Comune": "BONDENO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
    "Value 1": 63,
    "Value 2": 8,
    "Value 3": 17,
    "DANNO": 6,
    "Somma valori": 88,

  },
  {
    "": 1,
    "Comune": "CAVEZZO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 3.75,
    "Value 1": 23,
    "Value 2": 2,
    "Value 3": 9,
    "DANNO": 8,
    "Somma valori": 34,

  }];

const createPlotArray = (data) => {
  let returnArray = [];
  data.forEach(item => {
    const sum = (item["Value 1"] + item["Value 2"]/item['DANNO']);
    returnArray.push(sum);
  });

  return returnArray;
};

var uno =createPlotArray(myJSON)

var datiedu3 = {


"labels": ['Somma lavori incompiuti', 'OO'],
 "datasets": [{
label: 'EEE',
data: [uno],
 backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
borderWidth: 1
}]
          };



                                                        function grafo2(dati, opzioni) {
                                                            var grafoline = document.getElementById('Chartline').getContext('2d');
                                                            new Chart(grafoline, {
                                                                type: 'line',
                                                                data: dati,
                                                                options: opzioni

                                                            });
                                                        };

                                    grafo2(datiedu3)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use Codepen for hosting your sample code. SO snippets can do the same:

```js
var myArr = [{
    "": 0,
    "Comune": "BONDENO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 4.25,
    "Value 1": 63,
    "Value 2": 8,
    "Value 3": 17,
    "DANNO": 6,
    "Somma valori": 88 },
  { "": 1,
    "Comune": "CAVEZZO",
    "PUNTEGGIOSCUOLA1516": 3.75,
    "Value 1": 23,
    "Value 2": 2,
    "Value 3": 9,
    "DANNO": 8,
    "Somma valori": 34 }];
                         // you need to supply "labels" for each value!
var datiedu3 = {"labels": ['Somma lavori incompiuti','1','2','3','4','5','6'], 
              "datasets": [{label: 'EEE',
                         // data: myArr.map(itm=>itm['Value 1']+itm['Value 2']/itm.DANNO), 
                            data: [2,4,8,16,32,64,10], // enter any array you like!
                            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                            borderWidth: 1}] 
               };
function grafo2(dati, opzioni) {
  var grafoline = document.getElementById('Chartline').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(grafoline, {type: 'line',data: dati,options: opzioni});
};
// display the data used in dataset[0]:
// console.log(datiedu3.datasets[0].data)
grafo2(datiedu3)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<div id="linechartContainer">
<canvas id="Chartline"></canvas>
</div>
```

I replaced your function `createPlotArray()` with a simple `.map()` method applied to your input array `myArr`. Yes, it *actually is* an Array and *not* a JSON string.

The chart you specify is of `{type: 'line'...}`, so you should not be surprised that you don't get a bar-chart.

And, btw., I removed the `[]`around your data array `uno`. In my code I did not even generate this intermediate variable but placed the generated array directly into the `datiedu3` object as `data`-property.

Comment: thank you very much, but I wanted to add another array in data (not summed or anything), how could I do it?